# Is lambda expression an improved and essential version of anonymous class in java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class

May I say that?

Anonymous class looks like OO style while lambda expression makes it functional style.

Comment: Yes, a lambda in Java is the same as a `SMC` or "Single Method Class".

Comment: Difference between them: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2014-March/004050.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you asking about lambdas in Java 8?

A Java 8 lambda is a simplification for a subset of anonymous classes -- namely, anonymous classes that extends a "functional interface", and has exactly one method, does not use `this`, does not use initializer blocks, and has no fields. (However, this is a very common use case for anonymous classes.)

In other words, any lambda expression can be re-written into an equivalent anonymous class creation expression. But only some (not all) anonymous class creation expressions can be re-written into a lambda expression.

Comment: The `this` reference can still be used in a lambda, but it refers to the class instance where the lambda expression resides.  Unlike anonymous classes,   there is no new object created (not semantically anyway) where `this` would refer to the new object, so `this` points to whatever `this` refers to outside of the lambda.  That means that you couldn't use `this` in a lambda created in a static function, because there is no `this` to  refer to.

Comment: To be precise, "exactly one method" isn't accurate -- "exactly one abstract method" would be more precise, but the most accurate would be "exactly one abstract method not already declared in Object" would be most accurate.